# Validar enteros antes de agregarlos a una lista

Tags: python, lista, validación, condiciones

Estoy tratando de llenar una lista en python con enteros que cumplan ciertas condiciones (sean mayores a 1 y que no existan repeticiones), pero no logro hacerlo ya que al pasar más de 3 el programa marca el error:

> list index out of range

este es el código:

```
while True:
    N=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros para calcular el MCM "))
    if N>=2:
        break
    print("Ingrese un numero valido mayor o igual a 2 para el MCM.")
Num=[]
for i in range(N-1):
    num=int(input(f"Ingrese el numero entero en la posicion {i+1} "))
    if i>0:
     if num == Num[i-1] or num <=1:
        print("Valor incorrecto ")
        print("Los valores no se pueden repetir ni ser menores a 2.")
        Num.append(num)
        i=i-1
    else:
        if num<=1:
            print("Valor incorrecto ")
            print("Los valores no se pueden repetir ni ser menores a 2.")
            Num.append(num)
            i=i-1
```

Comment: Hola! Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pues cómo la tienes formulada no es posible responderla. Espero que puedas resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Te estás haciendo un lio con las condiciones, el error que comentas se produce en la segunda iteración en la linea:

```
if num == Num[i-1] or num <=1:
```

y se debe a que **en la primera iteración no agregas nada a la lista**. En la primera iteración `i` es 0, por lo que `if i>0` no se cumple y entramos en el `else`. Si ingresas un número válido `if num<=1` tampoco se cumple por lo que el `append` nunca se ejecuta.

Ten presente que el `append` solo debe tener lugar si el número ingresado es válido, en tu caso tiene lugar cuando el número es inválido. Además, si se ingresa un valor no válido no se le vuelve a pedir al usuario, sino que se pasa al siguiente.

Además de esto, tienes otro error en la lógica del programa. No quieres que existan repeticiones, pero para evitarlo solo comparas el número ingresado con el último ingresado. Imagina que `N` es `3` y se han ingresado como los dos primeros valores  4 y 7, si el usuario ingresa como tercer número otro 4, como 4 != 3 sería válido... Debes comprobar que el número no exista en la lista completa, no solo que sea diferente al último ingresado.

Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que la variable `i` se asigna en el `for`, hacer `i = i - 1` solo tendrá efecto en dicha iteración, cuando el `for` vuelve a iterar continuará con su cuenta original ignorando tu asignación:

> ```
> >>> for i in range(5):
>         print(i)
>         i = i - 1
>
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```

Como no sabes cuantas veces vas a necesitar iterar (cuantas veces el usuario ingresará un valor no válido), un ciclo `while` es más útil que un `for`.

```
while True:
    n = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros para calcular el MCM "))
    if n >= 2:
        break
    print("Ingrese un numero valido mayor o igual a 2 para el MCM.")

nums = []
i = 0
while i < n:
    num = int(input(f"Ingrese el numero entero en la posicion {i + 1} "))
    if num in nums:
        print("Valor incorrecto ")
        print("Los valores no se pueden repetir.")
    elif num <= 1:
        print("Valor incorrecto ")
        print("Los valores no pueden ser menores a 2.")
    else:
        nums.append(num)
        i += 1 

print(nums)
```